# Why does clang give a warning: unterminated ‘#pragma pack (push, …)’ at end of file?

Tags: c++, clangd

I create a main.cpp in my vscode with *clangd* enabled, and put the following code in it.

*clangd* warns the first line with the warning message:

> warning: unterminated ‘#pragma pack (push, …)’ at end of file

The whole content of main.cpp:

```
#pragma pack(push) // warning on this line
#pragma pack(1)
struct A
{
    int   a;
    short b;
    char  c;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

See also: https://releases.llvm.org/13.0.0/tools/clang/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wpragma-pack

I think it's a very common usage of `#pragma pack(push)`, I don't understand why the warning is generated.

More strange to me, if I add a semicolon before the first line, the warning disappears.

```
;                  // Add a semicolon
#pragma pack(push) // The warning disappears
#pragma pack(1)
struct A
{
    int   a;
    short b;
    char  c;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

**What's the reason behind?**

Comment: And what's before the pragma?

Comment: It is a compiler instruction...

Comment: No other code in the main.cpp, all code is pasted here. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: This is not a campiler warning. It has more to do with code analysing plugins.

Comment: Does it still warn if you do: ```#pragma pack(push, 1)``` ?

Comment: @robthebloke yes. still warn.

Comment: Does adding a newline at the end of the file resolve the issue? (That is, adding an extra blank line?) My clang-cl *only* warns about the not having a newline at the end of file. Not sure why adding the semicolon resolves the issue, though.

Comment: @AdrianMole no effect after adding extra new lines to the source file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug in clangd, tracked in https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1167.

Please see that issue for an explanation of why this currently happens.

---

A possible workaround discussed in that issue is to add a dummy declaration above the pragma to force clangd to end the file's "preamble" region before the pragma, e.g.:

```cpp
static_assert(true); // dummy declaration, ends the preamble
#pragma pack(push) // no warning!
#pragma pack(1)
struct A
{
    int   a;
    short b;
    char  c;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Note, if the file contains `#include` directives, for performance reasons those should remain in the preamble:

```cpp
#include <...>  // still in the preamble
static_assert(true); // dummy declaration, ends the preamble
#pragma pack(push) // no warning!
#pragma pack(1)
struct A
{
    int   a;
    short b;
    char  c;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

---

An alternative workaround would be to suppress the warning with a `.clangd` file that contains

```
Diagnostics:
    Suppress: pragma-pack
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug:  https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1167

But as a temporary workaround, you could suppress the error with a `.clangd` file that contains

```
Diagnostics:
    Suppress: pragma-pack
```

Comment: This adds very little to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72907523/10871073) and would perhaps be better as a comment on - or edit to - that answer.